# SQL - Use a not-variable variable to limit record count?

Tags: sql, salesforce

**Situation**: We've integrated Salesforce's Marketing Cloud with an autodialer to aid in getting in touch with leads. The team's availability is variable, and the last thing we want is to blast *too many* calls, resulting in people just waiting in queue. So, I'm going to provide the team's manager with a web form where she can enter a number of leads to have the system call.

**Problem**: [Marketing Cloud's SQL Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_sql_reference.htm&type=5) does not support variables. So, while I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT TOP @X lead.phone FROM lead WHERE lead.status = 'Open' ORDER BY lead.dateCreated DESC
```

This just can't be done.

**My Question to You, Oh SQL Guru's**: Is there another way that I can go about solving this problem?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, is there a table where you are trying to fetch data from ? I did not see any `from` on the query.

Comment: @stackFan - indeed, I missed the FROM when cutting the query into the question. This is a mock query to point out the fact that I *cannot* use @X - as Marketing Cloud doesn't allow variables. Please do not let my mistake distract you from the question at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a SQL solution, I was able to:

- Use a Webform to collect a number of leads to target
- Use AMPScript to store this number in a Data Extension
- Use an SSJS activity to get the number of leads needed for the list

The big caveat is that SSJS Row Lookups max at 2000 rows. For this project, this was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed a `from lead` keyword while selecting from one of the table.

Comment: If only life were that easy. Regardless of missing the from (which is very necessary to run the statement) - the @X is not allowed in Marketing Cloud. Let me see if I can clarify the question some...

Answer (score 0):

I have to be honest that I have not done much with Marketing Cloud's SQL however normal SQL you do not need to use dot notation unless you are referring to an inner join:

```
SELECT phone FROM lead WHERE status = 'Open' ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
```

Secondly have you tried using Local Variable declaration?

```
DECLARE @myLocalDateVar DATE
SET @myLocalDateVar = (SELECT Value FROM Custom WHERE Name = 'My Custom Name')
SELECT phone
FROM lead
WHERE status = 'Open' AND dateCreated > @myLocalDateVar
ORDER BY dateCreated DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the SQL engine in Marketing Cloud throws an error when trying to declare variables. The first word in any statement *must* be 'SELECT'. It's quite the conundrum. Also, the variable is in the number of records needing to be grabbed, not the date. Though this may be a mute point, since variables can't be declared.